# Is there a way to get behavior similar to default(T) using reflection?

Tags: .net, generics, reflection, .net-3.5

I'm refactoring some code that was originally designed with generics to also work with reflection.  The particular code base has `default(T)` scattered throughout.  I've created a method that will look similar named Default(T), but I don't think my implementation is correct.

Essentially my implementation looks like this:

```
private object Default(Type type)
{
    return (type.IsByRef ? (object)null : 0;
}
```

I am getting class cast exceptions.  The purpose of the reflection is to enable attributes to drive the functionality instead of the explicitly declaring objects.  Basically we have one set of attributes to mark properties that will get serialized, and now we want to use those same attributes to populate a property dialog box.  Because I'm working reflectively, generics are out of the picture.